# listview('refresh') don't work

Tags: android, jquery, html, listview, cordova

I'm developing an app for Android using Phonegap and JQuery. It works with db Sqlite.

When I add items to the listview dynamically, css styles don't work properly. I've tried to used listview('refresh') in all possible ways. Here is my code:

```
    $("#nextDay").click(function(){

    if (opDay < 6){
        opDay=opDay+1;
        db.transaction(queryDB,errorCB);
                $('#SheduleList').html(data);

    }
    else {
        opDay=1;
        db.transaction(queryDB,errorCB);
    }
    $('#SheduleList').listview('refresh');  
   });



    function querySuccess(tx,result){
    //$('#SheduleList').empty();
    $.each(result.rows,function(index){
        var row = result.rows.item(index);
        $('#SheduleList').append('<li id=li'+row['pair_id']+'><a href="#"><h3 class="ui-li-heading">'+row['pair_name']+'</h3><p class="ui-li-desc">'+row['teach_name']+", "+row['Aud_num']+", "+row['time']+'</p></a></li>');
    });

    $("#SheduleList").page();
    $('#SheduleList').listview();

}
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call this for dynamically populated container after append is done.

as

```
$("#SheduleList").page()
```

Comment: i've tried it now, but it doesn't help, new items still don't look like listview.

Comment: i've updated the code. screenshot of the program if needed: http://floomby.ru/s1/z4KCF

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done by page refresh. You have to recreate the page data by calling `$("#index").trigger("pagecreate");`

I explained here in detail [jquery mobile page injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096369/jquery-mobile-page-injection/11098639#11098639)

Comment: definitely it will work. please share your full code for better solution